# How do I make a color background in java

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I need to make a frame pop up and have a color display on the screen with certain dimensions for the window using Jframe or something like that.

Comment: The Oracle tutorial, [How to Use Panels](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example");
frame.setBackground(Color.RED); //for color
frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100)); //for size
//...
```

OR for JPanel

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setBackground(Color.RED); //for color
panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100)); //for size
//...
```

Hope it is what you mean.